# HMVC Codeigniter: Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I got this error from another module. I wonder why and how to fix it. I tried hard to fix that, and it couldn't work still.

Here's my department controller:

```
function departmentname_check($str){

    $mysql_query = "select * from departments where department_name = '$str'";

    $update_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    if (is_numeric($update_id)){
        //this is an update
        $mysql_query .= " and id != $update_id";
    }

    $query = $this->_custom_query($mysql_query);
    $num_rows = $query->num_rows();

    if ($num_rows > 0)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('departmentname_check', 'The department name that you submitted is already exist.');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Code above is the callback function. I don't write the 'submit' function here because there's nothing wrong with it. In the 'submit' function, I call the _make_sure_is_special_admin() function

And here is where the real problem comes from

```
function _make_sure_is_special_admin(){

    $this->load->module('users');
    //attempt to get the ID of the user

    //start by checking for a session variable
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

    $query = $this->users->get_where($user_id);

    foreach ($query->result() as $item) {
        $user_level = $item->user_level;
    }

    if ($user_level > 0){
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        redirect('site_security/not_allowed');
    }

    return TRUE;

}
```

When I tried to simplify code above, for instance, directly declare the $user_level = 2, it works fine. But in the code above, it doesnt.

Thanks in advance for every advise you give.

Comment: why the foreach in the second function? each user should have 1 level as apparent by logic and your code so you could just do `$query->row()->user_level`. also your last comment indicates this may be `null` have you `var_dump`ed it? further how are the two functions connected i don't see a reference to one another.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that actually. I just want to get the user_level from the current admin that is login. That's how it works. By the way I have already fixed it. Simple, I just moved the callback function to other module and everything works fine. Thank you very much for your response mate, @Alex

Comment: the foreach comment was intended to simplify your code